# Height of stacked balls

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, spheres

if there are two balls (size 40 mm and 30mm) stacked in a tube of internal diameter of 50mm, how could you find the height from the bottom of the pipe to the top of the highest stacked ball?

Comment: Have you drawn a picture to see where all of those dimensions lie?  You may find the answer is easier to find when working with a picture instead of a word problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ and $B$ denote the midpoints of the two balls. Their radii are $15$ and $20$, so the distance between $A$ and $B$ is $15+20=35$. The horizontal distance between $A$ and $B$ is $50-15-20=15$, hence by Pythagoras theorem the vertical distance between $A$ and $B$ is
$$\sqrt{35^2-15^2}=10\sqrt{10}.$$
Then the total height of the stacked balls is $20+10\sqrt{10}+15=35+10\sqrt{10}\approx66.62277660\dots$